# Why is Flask opening the UI again even though the code is named 'index.html'?

Tags: python, html, flask, openai-api

I'm experiencing an issue with my web application where, upon submitting a form, the UI opens multiple times instead of executing the desired action once. I'm using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript for the front-end, and a server-side framework for handling the form submission.
This is my python code "

``

```
import openai
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

# Configure OpenAI API credentials
openai.api_key = 'OPEN-AI-API-KEY'
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/process', methods=['POST'])
def process():
    user_input = request.form.get('question')
    # Process the user input and perform AI operations
    ai_response = generate_ai_response(user_input)

    return render_template('index.html', response=ai_response)


    return render_template('index.html', ai_response=ai_response)

def generate_ai_response(input_text):
    response = openai.Completion.create(
        engine='davinci',  # Select the OpenAI language model of your choice
        prompt=input_text,
        max_tokens=50,     # Adjust the max number of tokens for the desired response length
        temperature=0.7,   # Adjust the temperature for controlling response randomness
        n=1,               # Specify the number of responses to generate
        stop=None          # Add a custom stop sequence if needed to control the response length
    )

    ai_response = response.choices[0].text.strip()
    return ai_response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

"'

And my html code is "

``

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Website</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: #444654; /* Dark gray background */
            margin: 0; /* Remove default body margin */
            padding: 0; /* Remove default body padding */
        }
        
        .container {
            display: flex;
        }
        
        .sidebar {
            width: 300px; /* Width of the dark gray sidebar */
            background-color: #333333; /* Dark gray color */
            color: #ffffff; /* Text color in the sidebar */
            padding: 20px;
            height: 100vh; /* Extend sidebar height to full viewport height */
        }
        
        .main-content {
            flex: 1;
            padding: 20px;
            color: #ffffff; /* Text color in the main content area */
        }
        
        .input-area {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
        
        .input-area input {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 10px;
            font-size: 16px;
        }
        
        .input-area button {
            padding: 10px 20px;
            font-size: 16px;
            background-color: #ffffff; /* White background for the button */
            color: #444654; /* Dark gray text color for the button */
        }
        
        .output-box {
            background-color: #707088; /* Lighter shade of #444654 */
            padding: 10px;
            color: #ffffff; /* Text color in the output box */
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function submitQuestion() {
            var question = document.getElementById('question').value;
            var outputBox = document.getElementById('output');
            outputBox.innerHTML = 'Loading...';

            fetch('/process', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                },
                body: 'question=' + encodeURIComponent(question),
            })
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(response => {
                outputBox.innerHTML = response;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
                outputBox.innerHTML = 'An error occurred.';
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <h2>Chat List</h2>
            <ul>
                <!-- Add your user-added chats here -->
                <li>Chat 1</li>
                <li>Chat 2</li>
                <li>Chat 3</li>
                <!-- ... -->
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="main-content">
            <!-- Your main content goes here -->
            <h1>Welcome to My Website</h1>
            <div class="input-area">
                <input type="text" id="question" placeholder="Ask a question">
                <button type="button" onclick="submitQuestion()">Submit</button>
            </div>
            <div class="output-box" id="output">
                <!-- Output content will be dynamically added here -->
            </div>
            {% if ai_response %}
            <div class="output-box">
                {{ ai_response }}
            </div>
            {% else %}
            <div class="output-box">
                <!-- Handle case when ai_response is not available -->
                Please note that the code you provided contains a placeholder for ai_response, which appears to be a template variable. You may need to update that portion of the code with the appropriate variable or logic based on your web framework or templating engine.
            </div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

"'`